# New user comes disabled but activated

Tags: joomla3.0

New installation of Joomla! 3. User registration gives me a problem that I cannot figure out how to solve:  all new users got registered and activated but not enabled so when they are trying to login error messages  "Login denied! Your account has been blocked" comes up. Checking on the back shows Activated but not Enabled.

I am using setting that will enable the user to register and use account right away without email confirmation.

The setting in User Management module are: 
Allow User Registration:Yes; 
New User Registration Group:Registered; 
New User Account Activation:None; 
Notification Mail to Administrators:None;

Answer (score 1):

Please specify which other component are you using for you current site.

Might be some plugin will disable the user while creating new user, try to disable user plugin one by one and check it works or not

Comment: I actually found out K2 plugin. Not sure what it does but once I disabled it the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Setting for your preference:

1. Allow user registration: Yes;
2. New user registration Group: Registered;
3. New User Account activation: **Self**;

Although this is not a coding problem, still the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With Self new user will receive an email with an activation link. The account will be activated when the user clicks the activation link. I set None; as joomla docs suggests: user account will be active immediately with no action required.BTW even if I use Self, after the link is clicked user still gets Login denied message